# php empty string htmlspecialchars()

Tags: php, string, htmlspecialchars

So, I am trying to use `htmlspecialchars()` to protect my website but unfortunately I got stuck in this code:

```
<?php

function wrap_nome($firstname, $lastname)
{
$join = htmlspecialchars($firstname, ENT_QUOTES) . ' ' . htmlspecialchars($lastname, ENT_QUOTES);
if (mb_strlen($join) > 32)
{
$text = substr($join,0,32);
return $text . " ...";
}
else
{
return $join;
}
}

$nome = wrap_nome($firstname, $lastname);

echo '<span style="color:#7F7F7F;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"><b>' . $nome . '</b></span>';

?>
```

Initially I thought that the problem maybe was the fact that the string `$nome` had double and single quotes, then I removed them and found out that `htmlspecialchars($lastname, ENT_QUOTES)` continues to be echoed and `htmlspecialchars($firstname, ENT_QUOTES)` continues to give me an empty string!

If I do this:

```
echo '<span style="color:#7F7F7F;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"><b>' . htmlspecialchars($nome, ENT_QUOTES) . '</b></span>';
```

... It wont output anything.

Any ideas of what is causing this ?

Comment: yes both variables echo nicely anywhere in the page

Comment: if i remove htmlspecialchars() everything works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars` returns `FALSE` if it gets an error, which happens if `$nome` contains any characters that can't be represented in the specified character set. The character set defaults to `ISO8859-1` before PHP 5.4, `UTF-8` since then, try using `htmlspecialchars($nome, ENT_QUOTES, 'iso8859-1')`.

If that doesn't work, see the list of character sets in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and use the appropriate one for your names.

Comment: What language is the name in?

Comment: Portuguese from Portugal

Comment: $nome = "F.á.b.i.o. .H.e.n.r.r.i.q.u.e."; from the database

Comment: What encoding is the DB using?

Comment: you where right the problem was the "á" caracter!!! I just removed it and it worked. I just have to find the correct character set

Comment: nope, default is "UTF-8 - Default. ASCII compatible multi-byte 8-bit Unicode"

Comment: It changed between versions, and I was looking at old documentation when I wrote my first answer. I've updated it.

Comment: "PHP prior to 5.4.0, ISO-8859-1 is used as the default."

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace

`htmlspecialchars($str,ENT_QUOTES );`

with

`htmlentities($st ,ENT_QUOTES ,"UTF-8");`

Comment: Why should the one function work if the other does not? And they are not the same!

Comment: It's not the function that matters, it's the `UTF-8` argument.

Comment: I know, but this should be in the answer.

Comment: So I get a downvote for adding the third argument character set? :(